# How do I make angular to only affect model and scope at the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am making an application where the user select an item then it will show the price of the item and the user need to input the qty, I want my form to automatically show the total (qty * price) after the user inputted the qty. Now how do I make my angular to show the total of only that row, what I am currently doing below will change all the rows and multiply with all the prices from all the row.

I want it that the total column will only show the total price * qty inputted at the same row only.

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = $('.price').text();
    $scope.qty = 0;
});
```

html

```
<div class='container' ng-app='myApp'>
    <table ng-controller='myCtrl'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' class='qty' ng-model='qty'></td>
            <td><div class='price'></td>
            <td><div class='total'>{{ qty * price }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' class='qty' ng-model='qty'></td>
            <td><div class='price'></td>
            <td><div class='total'>{{ qty * price }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So if a user inputted a qty at the first row, the total should only change at the first row (qty * price) at the first row.

Comment: How are you iterating the list of items?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo Using jquery ajax.

Comment: I'd take a look at [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

If your data (qty, price) looks like this:

```
$scope.items = [{
    "qty": 5,
    "price": 38
}, {
    "qty": 3,
    "price": 22
}, {
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 12
}];
```

You can loop over to show it with `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in items">
  <td>{{i.qty}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.qty * i.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

[image: Screenshot of the result]

### [Here is a demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q1noLe6/)

Comment: Thank you, but the qty is supposed to be input and it is inputted by user and the price is not static as in it depends on which item the user selected the the price changed accordingly and the user need to input the qty amount of the item.

Comment: @Charas How do you store / retrieve datas then?

Comment: @pistou using jquery ajax, after user selected an item in the list, using jquery ajax to retrieve item price and the changing the price column text.

Comment: @Charas My JSON object is the equivalent of the ajax result of your API. Here I just showed you the way to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same model qty for all the items, you will have to use an array of qty and then try on ng-repeat